# How can a paid/proprietary module be combined with an open-source platform?

Tags: license-compatibility, license-recommendation, paid-software

How could licences be chosen to allow this?

As an example, how are things done with paid addons with Prestashop?

Comment: Too broad - depends on the exact licenses involved.

Comment: @curiousdannii how could I make the question more specific? I know little about licenses.

Comment: @JamesPoulson It would likely be helpful if you could perhaps give a scenario with various details of the situation. Otherwise, yes, it is a little broad.

Comment: @Zizouz212 one scenario I am thinking of is the marketplace that Prestashop has as mentioned in the question. I don't know what licence they use for addons.

http://addons.prestashop.com/en/

Comment: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/398499-prestashop-module-licensing/

Answer (score 1):

According to the GNU Licenses FAQ [here](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLInProprietarySystem) and I quote

> However, in many cases you can distribute the GPL-covered software alongside your proprietary system. To do this validly, you must make sure that the free and non-free programs communicate at arms length, that they are not combined in a way that would make them effectively a single program.

So I think you can combine it with proprietary as long as it's in an arms length.
For eg, **Plugins/Add-ons,** but make sure the core working of your program is not completely depended on that plugin.

Some Open source licenses such as MIT or BSD does allow you to sub-licensing.
Again it depends on what license is used.

**Disclaimer: I'm just a programmer, not a laywer.**